# Is returning a void response for Service APIs a good practice?

Tags: refactoring, anti-patterns

I am planning to build APIs to perform CRUD operations.

I have the following APIs:

1. CreateEntry
2. UpdateEntry

For CreateEntry API, I am accepting CreateEntryRequest and CreateEntryResponse as request and response structures respectively.

For UpdateEntry API, I am accepting UpdateEntryRequest as request and I am not returning anything.

Is it a good practice to not return anything? However, for the UpdateEntry API, the client gets the HTTP 200 response if the API is successful.

What is the best way to model Update only APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to just return 200 without a response body on updates if the client only needs information that the update was successful or if you want to save bandwidth.

But it also really depends on what kind of update you are talking about. Is your update designed in a way that the client has to send all data of the entry? Or is it more like a patching where you only update a portion of the entry (or a child object of the entry).

If the latter is the case I would rather return the current version of the entry as other clients might have changed another portion of the entry as well since you last fetched it. Or at least make sure that the object is fetched after the update by the client if again performance or bandwidth of the update request is your priority.